# What is difference between service plan and App service plan in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

Is there any difference between term "service plan" and "App service plan" in Azure? In one of the case I received following error - "Resource health status is not available for Load Balancer using current service plan. To enable health status, consider upgrading to a Standard service plan." 
So I have tried to search on this topic but getting results for "App service plan" only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Load Balancers come with 2 SKUs. Basic and Standard. You are using basic, health status is not available for this SKU. You should upgrade to Standard SKU to enable this.

App Service Plan and Load Balancer SKU are not tied in any way, shape or form.

Comment: created new LB with standard SKU. Now able to fetch health status.